# Hide data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have five button which contain different data

```js
$(".Datanewpost").click(function() {
  $(".data).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div id="Datanewpost">
    Data 1
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </diV>
  <div id="Datanewpost">
    data 2
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Datanewpost">
    data 3
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Datanewpost">
    data 5
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Datanewpost">
    data 5
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this does not work what do I need to do to get what I want? I know I can do it by assigning individual id to each div but that looks bad coding

NOTE: I want to be able to hide or show  individually  ,

Comment: Your divs all have the same id. ids have to be unique. And the selector you use looks at the class Datanewpost , where no element has that class. So instead of using the same id for every post, use the same class.

Comment: syntax error in `$(".data).toggle;` should be `$(".data").toggle()`

Comment: You have two very obvious issues. Firstly you're missing the closing `"` in the selector in the jQuery object and the repeated `id` needs to be changed to a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id should be unique in a document, use class instead. You can use `$(this).find('.data')` to toggle the specific element:

```js
$(".Datanewpost").click(function(){
  $(this).find('.data').toggle();
});
```

```css
.data{color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-main">
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 1
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </diV>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 2
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 3
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 4
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 5
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As in comment, you have asked to close the open `div` when clicking another, simply loop through all the `.data` except the current one. Then check `display='block'` property to set that to `display='none'`:

```js
$(".Datanewpost").click(function(){
  $(this).find('.data').toggle();
  var current = $(this).find('.data');
  $('.data').not(current).each(function(i, el){
    if(this.style.display=='block')
      this.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
.data{
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-main">
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 1
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </diV>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 2
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 3
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 4
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 5
      <div class="data">  Hello</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to hide or show  individual , like when u click one button does not affext other button ,

Comment: @user9964622, current solution is doing the exact. When you click `Data1`, it only hide, show the next `hello` to it...........same goes for all........thanks

Comment: I tried but it hide all helo  check here https://jsfiddle.net/yjs7nbov/2/

Comment: @user9964622, there is something wrong with the HTML, I have used from my answer and is working nicely......thanks

Comment: @user9964622, I have got the issue of why the code in the fiddle not working as expected.....you have one `</diV>` (capital V). Should be `</div>`

Comment: Thanks for help but still when I click any button its hide and show all data (helo)

Comment: I want when a user click eg the first button its show or hide only data 1  helo not all as its now

Comment: @user9964622, there is no closing `</div>` for first `<div class="Datanewpost">`....that's why it is going all the way down to the match the closing `div`.........hope it clears the issue.

Comment: okay now works, so if I want when user clicks one buttom and decide to click another button its should close the opened one, what do I need to do?

Comment: @user9964622, I have added the second solution for that......please check......thanks.

Comment: Thanks bro I have figured it out too ,  thanks alot , If I want the to push down the below div when the hidden is shown what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple same elements, you should use a `class` instead of `id` like the following:

```js
$(".Datanewpost").click(function () {
  $(this).find(".data").toggle();
});
```

```css
.Datanewpost {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 1
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </diV>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    data 2
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    data 3
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    data 5
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    data 5
    <div class="data"> Helol</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hii , does this hide each element indiviadual ?

Comment: @user9964622 hi, yes

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
$(".Datanewpost").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".data").toggle();
```

});

Comment: will this hide indivudual ?  when u click first button it should hide or show only its data not all

Comment: Yes will this hide individual.